# Github api not listing private repos

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to get all the repos in my account, I have several private repos and 1 public repo, i do a get request to this endpoint https://api.github.com/users/$user/repos and I get only the public repo, I have my token with the repo scope and I use authorization type bearer but it just wont show the private repos, do you know what am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private repositories are not listed in the `/users/$user/repos` API, which comes a bit unexpected given that [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users) says *"allows to get public and private information about the authenticated user"*.

But you can retrieve them via the [`/user/repos` endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user) which lists *"repositories that the authenticated user has explicit permission to access."*.

This will include all repos you have, not just your own. You could of course filter by `owner.login` or `full_name` in the result to get what you want, but you can also query right away by adding a quer string `?type=private` to your URL.

Sample Python code:

```py
import requests
token = "****"
url = "https://api.github.com/user/repos?type=private"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"token {token}",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
for repo in r.json():
    print(repo["name"])
```

Comment: how do you get the github token tho?

Comment: @AliGuliyev – be logged in with GitHub and go https://github.com/settings/tokens to create a token. When generating a new token, you will be asked for the scopes that token shall be good for. For the above, check "repo" with it's subnodes.

Comment: okay, i have already fixed the issue but thanks for the response tho